# Help with a regular expression for a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Need help writing a regular expression to match any class containing the phrase `block-container`

I've come up with this: `'[class^=block-container]'` but I need help writing the wild cards around the phrase `block-container`.

Examples i need to match:

```
 nav-block-container-left
 block-container-whitebox
 right-block-container
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("[class*=block-container]")
```

Comment: That worked, does the * tell it to find any string containing the words block-container? Explaining why ^ only included it if block-container was at the beginning of the string. If that is correct it makes a lot more sense now. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the *= is the "contains" selector. The ^= is the "starts with" selector. They're all listed here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Yes. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ . *= is "contains" while ^= is "starts-with".

Answer (score 1):

You're so close! This is what you want, the *= selector. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Like this:

```
$('*[class*=block-container]').fadeOut();
```

I tested it on a page that has .  And then did:
    $('*[class*=opmen]').fadeOut();

And it faded out the topmenu div.

Comment: +1 - Because I know you were working on this at the same time as Mark Ursino since you included the '*' before the first '[' that i editted out right after posting.